# Can you Extract the Signature of all the Methods inside a Class?

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

assuming I have this class:

```
class Actions {
  static FooAction = 'foo' as const;
  someAction1() {
    return {
     type: Actions.FooAction,
     payload: {a: 1, b:2}
  }}

  static BarAction = 'bar' as  const;
  someAction2() {
    return {
     type: Actions.BarAction,
     payload: {c: 3, e:2}
  }}
  ... keeps going ...
}
```

All the class method return a similar object: `{type: string, payload: Record<string, number>}`

However I would like to be more strict. I want it to be

```
type ReturnedActions = 
| { type: 'foo', {a: string, b:string} } 
| { type: 'bar', {c: string, e:string} } 
...
```

because than I can use a switch to filter by type:

```
declare var a: ReturnedActions 

switch (a.type) {
  case 'foo': 
    payload.c // error
}
```

I know I can do

```
var actions = new Actions(); 
type = ReturnType<typeof actions.someAction1> |  ReturnType<typeof actions.someAction2>
```

However this class is hundreds of lines long. Is there a way to extract all the possible return values from all the methods in the class without manually doing it?

I am using version "typescript": "3.7.2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to go through the properties of the class and a conditional type to filter methods and extract the return type. You then index this mapped type to get the union of all possible values in the mapped type

```
type ReturnedActions<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (...a: any) => infer R ? {
        type: P,
        payload: R
    } : never
}[keyof T]

type AllActions = ReturnedActions<Actions>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=28&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECCwBcCWB7AdjA3gKGtCCYyw0AYiivMutALzQDkAZhQ9JNMOgQNy74oAtgFMqqNAEYAFAEpoOPHgBOwhAFclaef0UIAngAdhALjiJxEAHTlK59ABodeA2D0gUYACanMYUxPtoACNjACYAX35wyP4CIiQSACEwJTEaegYglLYOTm4EPjwIIVE7NFDZbUVoFXVNKur9I1M0jEtk1LLHaugXNw9veWBTAGZAkwioyLxsGOwm4WgAJVUNNGFPVogAHgAVAD46BrwAbQAFaCQtAGthPRQmaF2AXVNd8+foYQAPBGE0TwwKSWEF+dhoPRyWiHK5MYRKZbQAD8xx6C1MZ26PWcrncXlMSyc4WgpnWADd4bMTrd7o8Xth5oZFrAQCAtkcVnV1psyjstvsGUA)

**Edit**
If `Actions` only contains functions, you can also use the distributive nature of `ReturnType` to get the return type of all functions in `Actions`:

```
type AllActions = ReturnType<Actions[keyof Actions]>;
```

Comment: you can also do this using `ReturnType` and not declare `ReturnedActions`; 
`type AllActions = ReturnType<Actions[keyof Actions]>;`
If you want to add that to your answer

Comment: @lonewarrior556 fair enough, that is possible as well, but only works if all public members of `Actions` are functions. It was not necessarily clear to me that was the case

Comment: Ahh, well that info also helps. Thanks!